# How do I populate the 'cause' parameter of $exceptionHandler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a decorator to define custom behavior for [$exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler), and am trying to test it.

When it gets called, it receives two parameters, 'exception' and 'cause'. I can't seem to find any documentation about how to populate the 'cause' parameter. How do I throw an exception so that parameter is not null?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `$exceptionHandler` does by default is log to the console with the given parameters:

```
function $ExceptionHandlerProvider() {
  this.$get = ['$log', function($log) {
    return function(exception, cause) {
      // .apply means delegate the arguments
      $log.error.apply($log, arguments); // just delegate the arguments
    };
  }];
}
```

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/exceptionHandler.js#L45-L47)

So when you decorate it, just like the *first* parameter is the exception, the second parameter is the cause. You can't `throw` an exception and expect the parameter not to be null though. This is because throughout the Angular codebase information is not passed to it - for example in promises, the following code calls it:

```
} catch (e) {
   deferred.reject(e);
   exceptionHandler(e);
}
```

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L323)

As you can see - a second parameter will never be passed in this case (which is quite a common one). So I'm afraid that if you want to use `cause` you'll have to decorate every single place in Angular that calls `$excpetionHandler` or just use it in your own code.